# Bing maps Version 8. Customize zoom buttons

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'am using bing maps version 8.
I would like to customize the zoom (in/out) buttons.

- use custom icons
- use custom position (set in the top left, not in the    right)

I've already customize the pushpin icon ([link](https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#createPushpinFromImage+JS))
But I don't know how to customize the zoom buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize the zoom buttons you have to hide the default ones and create custom ones separately. Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map;

    function GetMap()
    {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'YourBingMapsKey',
            showZoomButtons: false  //Hide the default zoom buttons and create custom ones.
        });

        document.getElementById('zoomIn').onclick = function () {
            var z = map.getZoom() + 1;
            map.setView({ zoom: z });
        }

        document.getElementById('zoomOut').onclick = function () {
            var z = map.getZoom() - 1;
            map.setView({ zoom: z });
        }

        updateZoomButtons();
    }

    function updateZoomButtons() {
        switch (map.getMapTypeId()) {
            case Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.birdseye:
            case Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial:
            case Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.canvasDark:
                document.getElementById('zoomOut').className = 'darkZoom';
                document.getElementById('zoomIn').className = 'darkZoom';
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById('zoomOut').className = 'lightZoom';
                document.getElementById('zoomIn').className = 'lightZoom';
                break;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&branch=experimental' async defer></script>

    <style>
        .mapContainer, #myMap{
            position:relative;
            width:800px;
            height:600px;
        }

        #zoomOut, #zoomIn {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 25px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 33px;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            border-radius: 16px;
            -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        #zoomOut {
            line-height: 24px;
            top: 220px;
        }

        #zoomIn {
            top:160px;
            line-height:30px;
        }

        .darkZoom{
            background-color: #333333;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
            color:white;
        }

        .darkZoom:hover{
            background-color: #808080;
        }

        .lightZoom{
            background-color: white;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            color: black;
        }

         .lightZoom:hover{
            background-color: #CCCCCC;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mapContainer">
        <div id="myMap"></div>
        <span id="zoomOut">‒</span>
        <span id="zoomIn">+</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The zoomIn and zoomOut work OK. However when I use the custom zoom(in/out) there is no animation. The change from zoom=x to zoom=x+1 (or x-1) is very abrupt. Do you know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, and I haven't used Bing maps for a while, but I believe there isn't any animation options exposed in the API. If you are early in your development, you may want to take a look at Azure Maps which has a lot more animation support and supports much larger data sets. https://azure.com/maps